# Rewriting URLs with MVC/Endpoint Routing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get URL rewrites to work in combination with MVC/endpoint routing.  Here are the relevant parts of my Startup.Configure method:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RewriteRuleTest()));

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

And RewriteRuleTest:

```
public class RewriteRuleTest : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Path.Value.ToLower() == "/index")
        {
            request.Path = "/Home/Privacy";
            context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to follow what is recommended, but I get a 404 when I hit /index.  I can hit a breakpoint set inside the if statement above.  I can also navigate directly to /Home/Privacy and that works fine.  I've tried all three options for RuleResult.  Why won't the rewrite serve up the modified URL?

Comment: I just tested and confirmed this works if I use app.UseMvc instead of app.UseEndpoints.  I think I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to put the url rewriter middleware before `app.UseRouting()`:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RewriteRuleTest()));
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **DynamicRouteValueTransformer**.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("{language}/{controller}/{action}");
        });

public class TranslationTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
{
    private readonly TranslationDatabase _translationDatabase;

    public TranslationTransformer(TranslationDatabase translationDatabase)
    {
        _translationDatabase = translationDatabase;
    }

    public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if (!values.ContainsKey("language") || !values.ContainsKey("controller") || !values.ContainsKey("action")) return values;

        var language = (string)values["language"];
        var controller = await _translationDatabase.Resolve(language, (string)values["controller"]);
        if (controller == null) return values;
        values["controller"] = controller;

        var action = await _translationDatabase.Resolve(language, (string)values["action"]);
        if (action == null) return values;
        values["action"] = action;

        return values;
    }
}
```

more info https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/